# 403 forbidden when login in harbor 2.0.1 in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am installed harbor v2.0.1 in kubernetes v1.18, now when I am login harbor, it give me this tips:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"FORBIDDEN","message":"CSRF token invalid"}]}
```

this is my traefik 2.2.1 ingress config(this is the [docs](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor-helm/blob/1.3.0/templates/ingress/ingress.yaml#L24) I am reference):

```
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`harbor-portal.dolphin.com`) && PathPrefix(`/c/`)
      services:
        - name: harbor-harbor-core
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`harbor-portal.dolphin.com`)
      services:
        - name: harbor-harbor-portal
          port: 80
```

I am check harbor core logs only show ping success message.Shoud I using https? I am learnging in local machine. Is https mandantory? I am searching from internet and find just a little resouce to talk aboout it.what should I do to make it work?

[image]

I read the source code, and tried in harbor core pod like this:

```
harbor [ /harbor ]$ curl --insecure -w '%{http_code}' -d 'principal=harbor&password=Harbor123456' http://localhost:8080/c/login   
{"errors":[{"code":"FORBIDDEN","message":"CSRF token invalid"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

my expose type is nodePort. modify the values.yaml file, "externalURL: https" change to "externalURL: http"

before: externalURL: https://10.240.11.10:30002
after: externalURL: http://10.240.11.10:30002

and then reinstall the harbor